# NameError: name 'df' is not defined(Python)

Tags: python-3.x

Below is the code i am trying to use in python, have tried everything.Can anyone please help ..

```
import pandas as pd
# Using DataFrame.astype() function
df["Date"] = df["Date"].astype('datetime64[ns]')
print (df.dtypes)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[24], line 3
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 # Using DataFrame.astype() function
----> 3 df["Date"] = df["Date"].astype('datetime64[ns]')
      4 print (df.dtypes)

NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

I had tried to import library and other google solution but not solved.

Comment: You've not defined `df`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array name is not defined in python NameError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784484/array-name-is-not-defined-in-python-nameerror)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You never define the DataFrame `df` through `df = pd.DataFrame()`. Try

```py
import pandas as pd

# Define df
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date"])

# Using DataFrame.astype() function
df["Date"] = df["Date"].astype('datetime64[ns]')
print(df.dtypes)
```

Comment: File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3804, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3802     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803 except KeyError as err:
-> 3804     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3805 except TypeError:
   3806     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3807     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3808     #  the TypeError.
   3809     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 'Date'

Comment: you suggestion works very well but again stuck at above error

Comment: @aryan I've adjusted my solution accordingly. It now creates a DataFrame with an empty "Date" column first and then changes the datatype of it to "datetime64[ns]". Hope this helps :)